webauthn section in the Apple App Site Association (AASA) file
Suppose I cannot cannot host the AASA file on the root domain, how can I ensure the subdomain configuration includes the necessary details to handle the WebAuthn process.
{
"webcredentials": {
    "apps": [
        "*******.com.click.cas"
    ]
},
"webauthn": {
    "fido2": [
        {
            "rpId": "click.co",
            "origin": "https://froze.sit.click.co"
        }
    ]
}

}
. Is this correct ?

If you want to check the domain and domain configuration. There is website like this. You can check it from there if you want.
AASA Validator: https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/
